# How to check if any value of the columns in my table consist trailing spaces in MS ACCESS 2003?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

How can i check if any of the values of my columns in TABLEA consist trailing spaces? 
I only know how to check if there are trailing spaces from one column but not all.

```
       SELECT *  
       FROM TABLEA
       WHERE Col1 LIKE ('* ');
```

As i have 45 columns in my table, it will be very tiring to specify all in the where clause. Currently i am doing it manually by tab - ing through the columns and rows, any better suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do an RTrim on all your columns and insert them back

```
Select RTrim(Col1) As TrimmedCol1, Rtrim(Col2) As TrimmedCol2,. . . . 
From TABLEA
```

If you have a Counter for the primary key, you can insert the result into the same table and delete the origional values.  If not, the best way is to insert these values into a temp table.

```
INSERT INTO TempTable (Col1, Col2,....)
 Select RTrim(Col1) As TrimmedCol1, Rtrim(Col2) As TrimmedCol2,. . . . 
    From TABLEA
```

If you would like to just get the rows with trailing spaces, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE 
Col1 <> RTrim(Col1) OR
Col2 <> RTrim(Col2) OR
...
Col44 <> RTrim(Col44)
```

Comment: @ta.speot.is, you're right, I am going out on a limb and presuming that lc. doesn't want the trailing spaces.

Comment: Your answer is not too far off the actual answer, so you could edit it?

Comment: @ta.speot.is, what did you have in mind...  Col1 <> RTrim(Col1)?

Comment: this is just as tedious as me specifying 45 columns in my where clause with LIKE, any other suggestion? i just need to check. Its a data consistency check process i am doing

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought you were to the point where you were tabbing trough your cells?  Copy and pasting 40 or so times doesn't seem like that much tedium to me with respect to managing a database.  I'll withdraw my answer if I don't get any plus votes in the next 15 minutes.

Comment: I voted you up for your effort and the fact that i might be confusing you. Maybe i am not clear enough. This table i have 45 fields, my next table has 67 fields and one table has 79 field. I am just looking for efficient alternatives

Comment: Thanks,  Your only other option (that I can think of) is to write a VBA script to go through each record recursively, but unless you have more than a dozen tables or so, it won't be worth the effort.  I don't have Access at home, so I can't try this, but have you tried just doing a Ctrl-F for "* "?

Answer (score 2):

I am uncertain about exactly what you want.  If you want only the names of the text columns whose values include trailing spaces, you can use a custom VBA function.

I added trailing spaces to values in 2 columns in my `tblFoo` table.  Using the function below, I get the names of those columns in the Immediate window.

```vb
? ColumnsWithTrailingSpaces("tblFoo")
some_text, Trans Type

Public Function ColumnsWithTrailingSpaces(ByVal pTable As String) As String
    Dim db As DAO.database
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim strReturn As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each fld In db.TableDefs(pTable).Fields
        Select Case fld.Type
        Case dbText, dbMemo
            If DCount("*", pTable, _
                "Right([" & fld.Name & "], 1) = ' '") > 0 Then
                strReturn = strReturn & ", " & fld.Name
            End If
        Case Else
            'pass
        End Select
    Next fld
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    If Len(strReturn) > 0 Then
        strReturn = Mid(strReturn, 3)
    End If
    ColumnsWithTrailingSpaces = strReturn
End Function
```

If you also wanted to discard the trailing spaces, you could do that by modifying the function so that it creates and executes an `UPDATE` statement (instead of just adding the field name to `strReturn`).

```vb
strUpdate = "UPDATE [" & pTable & "]" & vbCrLf & _
    "SET [" & fld.Name & "] = RTrim([" & fld.Name & "]);"
db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
```

If you want to see all those rows where any of the text columns includes one or more trailing space, you can build a query whose `WHERE` clause references the field names returned by the `ColumnsWithTrailingSpaces()` function.

```vb
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
WHERE
       Right(Col1,  1) = ' '
    OR Right(Col9,  1) = ' '
    OR Right(Col42, 1) = ' '
```

If none of those suggestions gives you what you want, please clarify what you want.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only way to do it is to specify all columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
WHERE Col1 LIKE ('* ')
OR Col2 LIKE ('* ')
OR ...
```

Suggestion: Copy the table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) out to a text editor and do some magic search-replace to create the statement.

Comment: Thats the sure case to do but its very tedious. Let me go search for easier way, else yours will definitely be the answer